# use-package :defer t and autoloads

Tags: use-package, autoload

My understanding is if that I use any of `:commands`, `:bind`, `:bind*`, `:bind-keymap`, `:bind-keymap*`, `:mode`, or `:interpreter`, then it will create a corresponding autoload and defer loading of the package until that autoload is triggered.

I'm confused about the situations in which the package will load given that I don't use any of the above sections and I set it to `:defer t`.

I see this in the readme:

> Typically, you only need to specify `:defer` if you know for a fact that some other package will do something to cause your package to load at the appropriate time, and thus you would like to defer loading even though use-package isn't creating any autoloads for you.

If I know for a fact that package X has "built-in" autoloads (i.e. autoloads defined by the package author), then can I simply set `:defer t` and rely on those to load the package at the appropriate time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I know for a fact that package X has "built-in" autoloads (i.e. autoloads defined by the package author), then can I simply set `:defer t` and rely on those to load the package at the appropriate time?

Yes, that's exactly what that means.  Similarly, you can also use `:defer t` in place of something like `:mode` or `:interpreter` if the package already handles its `auto-mode-alist` or `interpreter-mode-alist` assignments correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there's a more convenient and reliable way to see if a package contains autoloads than scouring through the package's directory in my elpa/ dir and looking to see if there are any autoloads defined? I'm confused because I get the impression that this is [done automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26363815/101090) if I use package.el and MELPA (which I do), so does that mean that I can safely specify `:defer t` on all of the packages I install from MELPA?

Comment: What I do is use `describe-function` (`C-h f`) on whatever command I'd like to use as an entry point.  If it's been natively autoloaded (i.e., as part of the package rather than your `use-package` declaration), the help buffer will describe it as something like "an autoloaded compiled Lisp function" in the first line.  And yes, the autoloads should be set up automatically by package.el.