# when to use defer in use-package?

Tags: use-package

Quoting from [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#modes-and-interpreters)

> If you aren't using :commands, :bind, :bind*, :bind-keymap, :bind-keymap*, :mode, or :interpreter (all of which imply :defer; see the docstring for use-package for a brief description of each), you can still defer loading with the :defer keyword:

But why I found many people including [jwiegley](https://github.com/jwiegley/dot-emacs/blob/fe21cafc748d6130f5bb8f105a698c5bda2b7e72/dot-org.el#L989) himself still use `:defer` even it's already have `:bind`

Comment: The example you linked from Wiegley's configuration uses `:defer 5` (not just `:defer` on its own) to load the package automatically after 5 seconds.

Comment: @azzamsa this probably helps: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19694/19819

Answer (score 4):

The answer is present on `use-packages`'s [GitHub page](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#notes-about-lazy-loading) under section "Notes about lazy loading". To quote,

> In almost all cases you don't need to manually specify `:defer t`. This is implied whenever `:bind` or `:mode` or `:interpreter` is used. **Typically, you only need to specify `:defer` if you know for a fact that some other package will do something to cause your package to load at the appropriate time, and thus you would like to defer loading** even though use-package isn't creating any autoloads for you.